# Unable to add window -- token null while clicking dynamically created vidoview

Tags: android

I am working on an Application in which i create multiple dynamic videoviews on notification from server. The problem is when i click on the videoview it crashes the application as i did not add any Listner.Show following massege in logcat.

android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?`

```
private void LoadDynamincVideoViews(final String path, String ID) {
    final float scale = getApplicationContext().getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int pixels = (int) (200 * scale + 0.5f);
    int pixels1 = (int) (250 * scale + 0.5f);
    int height = (Devicewidth * 9 / 16);
    mVideoView = new VideoView(this);
    mVideoView.setTag(ID);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            pixels, height);
    params.setMargins(10, 5, 5, 5);
    mVideoView.setLayoutParams(params);
    mVideoViewArray.put(ID, mVideoView);

    mLinearBottom.addView(mVideoView);
    // HashMap< String, VideoView> hashmap = new HashMap<String,
    // VideoView>();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(
                    getApplicationContext());
            mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
            // mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoview);

            Uri video = Uri.parse(path);
            mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
            mVideoView.start();
        }
    }, 2000);

}
```

Comment: at android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:365)  at android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:325)    android.widget.VideoView.toggleMediaControlsVisiblity(VideoView.java:747)    at android.widget.VideoView.onTouchEvent(VideoView.java:688)at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8968)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what i think is that you have added  listeners, which is Mediacontroller when you click on VideoView it tries to show the controllers like stop/play button farward and backward button

> Remove     mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

and check if it works.

and try to add

```
   MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(Your_Activity_Name.this);
   mediaController.setAnchorView(_Video_Player);
  _Video_Player.setMediaController(mediaController);
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Mubeen its working I just commit mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

Comment: @ZulqarnainAlam Well Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

put  **newMediaController(MainActivity.this)** in setMediaController()

```
vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(MainActivity.this));
vv.requestFocus();
vv.start();
```